# SQL Server : LIKE operator is not returning the proper results if ESCAPE parameter is not defined

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a specific SQL Server 2008 instance, I'm trying to retrieve values with `LIKE` operator and it is working, UNLESS my search criteria is something like '(...)s%'.

I cannot really tell why, but searching for any term having an ending s%' criteria does not work. But defining ESCAPE char or placing % before the s, the results are retrieved.

It's a client SQL Server instance, so there might be SQL Server engine parameters previously defined that are causing this situation, or even Windows Server environment configs. Not having discarded any scenario, I've verified SQL engine configs with local and did not find any major differences. Windows Server regional settings in the client are English (United States), but updating local instance to the same regional setting did not provoke the same problem.

Here is an example of the performed queries:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE(value nvarchar(300))
INSERT INTO @mytable  VALUES('testa'),('testb'),('testc'),('tests'),('testz')

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'test%' --> Retrieves all results

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'testa%' --> Retrieves single result 'testa'

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'tests%' --> PROBLEMATIC QUERY: No results retrieved (should retrieve 'tests')

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'test%s%' --> Retrieves result problematic query does not return 'tests'

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'tests%' ESCAPE('\') --> Retrieves result problematic query does not return 'tests'

SELECT * FROM @mytable WHERE [value] LIKE 'tests%' ESCAPE('a') --> Retrieves result problematic query does not return 'tests'
```

Apparently it's not a database related issue, because I have the same problem when using system databases:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] LIKE 'm%' -->  retrieves 'master','model','msdb'

SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] LIKE 'mas%' --> PROBLEMATIC QUERY: no results retrieved

SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] LIKE 'ma%s%' --> Retrieves 'master'

SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] LIKE 'mas%' ESCAPE '\' --> Retrieves 'master'
```

Anyone had this issue before? Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Rui

**UPDATE**
So, for the instance where the problem verified, the client chose to migrate to a newer Windows/SQL Server version.
Therefore, I won't be able to test any solutions from now on. :\

Thanks for the comments everyone.
Best regards

Comment: This does not seem to be reproducible: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88503efe90db75af2cc65fe99a5ac839

Comment: Yes. this problem is specific to a single client instance (all other development, staging and client instances do not present this issue). 

Not really sure how I can present this issue for testing.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce, we can't guess what might be different about this single client instance. Is it a case sensitive instance? A case sensitive database? Are you sure the character data matches exactly to the character data in the where clause?

Comment: It's not a case sensitive issue. Using `LIKE` with S% presents the same issue. I usually use CS_AS in the database collation and this was never an issue. As refered above, this behaviour is happening when executing queries in `sys.databases`. Are there any SQL params/configs that can influence the final results worth verifying?

Comment: Question: I might be looking from the wrong perspective, but isn't it strange that the query works when I define the ESCAPE param with any char not in the expression? Also and still replying to Aaron: the data char is the same, because using this query and placing a % before the s, the results are correct.